# Intersection between subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be an even integer and $k$ the largest integer such that $2^k < n$. Let $S = \{\pm 2^0, \pm 2^1, \pm 2^2, \ldots, \pm 2^k \}$ considered as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ where we take representatives in $\{0, \ldots, n - 1\}$.

> **Example:**  For $n = 6$, $S = \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4 \} = \{1, 5, 2, 4\}$

Denote $jS = \{js : s \in S\}$ and $L = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}_n : \lceil n / 4 \rceil \leq x \leq \lfloor 3n / 4 \rfloor \}$. I need to show that $L \cap jS \neq \emptyset$ for all $j = 1 \ldots, n - 1$. Does anyone have an idea? I have checked with a computer that it is true up to $10^4$.

> **Example (continued):** We have $L = \{ 2, 3, 4\}$ and
>
> $1S = S = \{1, 2, 4, 5\}$, $L \cap 1S = \{ 2, 4 \}$
>
> $2S = \{ 2, 4\}$, $L \cap 2S = \{ 2, 4 \}$
>
> $3S = \{ 0, 3\}$, $L \cap 3S = \{ 3 \}$
>
> $4S = \{ 2, 4\}$, $L \cap 4S = \{ 2, 4 \}$
>
> $5S = S = \{1, 2, 4, 5\}$, $L \cap 5S = \{ 2, 4 \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound bite version: start with $j$ and keep doubling it until it lands in that center interval.

Rigorous proof: We may assume that $1\le j\le n/2$, for if $j>n/2$ then we may consider $n-j$ instead. Let $m$ be the smallest nonnegative integer such that $2^mj \ge n/4$. Note that $m\le k$, since $2^{k+1} \ge n$ by the definition of $k$ and so $2^kj \ge 2^k \ge n/2$. If $m=0$, then $j\in\jS\cap L$. If $m>0$, note that $2^{m-1}j < n/4$ by the definition of $m$, and so $2^mj < n/2$. Since $2^mj\ge n/4$ by definition, we conclude that $2^mj \in jS \cap L$.